# Force to Windows Authenticate programmatically

Tags: asp.net, security, windows-authentication

I have a single sign-on widget that authenticates people against our AD. We also have employee kiosks, machines accessed with a generic user account. That generic user account cannot be used as part of the single sign on. Meaning that those users **must** sign in with their real active directory accounts. The problem is those generic accounts do not belong to any roles. So I have to do that authentication in my code.

The app runs in Windows Authentication.

Is there any way to force certain users to Windows Authenticate from code? I do most of my custom authentication in global.asax..

Comment: OK, so there is Http.Context.SkipAuthrorization. Which is good to know, only I am looking for it's reverse alternative. It has to be somewhere in the depths of asp.net... Please help!

Comment: Do you mean that you have a widget being used in different web apps?  Or you have only one web app?  What is the meaning of generic user account?  Do you mean a local user account (Non AD user account)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used:

```
 <authorization>
    <denyRoles="RoleExcludeFromSSO">
 </authorization>
```

This way users from that role always have to enter their credentials.